# Can I pass Java Object in JpaRepository Class?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jparepository

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface CustomRepository extends JpaRepository<Object, Long> {

     @Query(value = "SELECT name FROM student", nativeQuery = true)
    List<String> getAllStudentNames();
}
```

Will this work if not what will be the solution for this? I don't want to create student Entity.

Comment: I do not understand why you do not want a Student Entity. Create one just with the field name and the query you entered will work simply by removing the "nativeQuery = true"

Comment: so my Student class will have only one field right but actual table have more fields so this wont be a issue and also not using id wont give any error?

Comment: `id` is required, but yes, you can just include `name` as a field.

Comment: That's what I am saying what else I can do?

Comment: What error did you get when you tried it using Object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not have a Student class then you should not make a JpaRepository for it. This is my suggestion:

```
@Repository
public class StudentRepository {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public List<String> findAllStudentNames() {
        return em.createNativeQuery("SELECT name FROM student").getResultList();
    }
}
```